# Eclipse X11 Forwarding Cent OS

Tags: eclipse, centos

I'm trying to get Eclipse to work on my CentOS 7 VM via X11 forwarding. The X11 forwarding seems to be working, as I am able to run and see "xclock". However, whenever I run Eclipse, it crashes with a message similar to this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
    /home/centos/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/375/0/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4527.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/centos/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk-4527.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Can't load library: /home/centos/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-pi-gtk.so
```

This issue is all over the web, and a lot of it is solved my soft linking files in `/usr/lib/jni/` to `~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/` but, I do not have a a `/usr/lib/jni` directory. So, I tried to find the libraries that create this folder upon installation and I found these in another Stack Overflow post: libswt-gtk-3-jni, libswt-gtk-3-java

And I can't seem to find anything on CentOS that provides these. I then found this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/3/html/User_Guide/chap-Eclipse.html#tabl-Eclipse-Components) on the CentOS client portal for installing Eclipse and it doesn't work for me. It talks about getting access to `devtoolset-3` via RedHat Subscription Manager or RHN Classic, both of which are unavailable to me on the machine that I am working with.

At this point I have JDK installed, and Eclipse untarred and attempting to launch and I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at the [3.x version](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/3/html/User_Guide/sect-Eclipse-Install.html) of that toolkit guide?

Comment: @EtanReisner I did not, actually. Unfortunately, in order to install Eclipse you need access to the devtoolset-3 package, which is acquired through RHN Classic or RedHat Subscription Management. Both of which are things not available to me on the VM that I am working on. So, I'll just need to install it.